# How to transfer input to lambda which is triggered by change in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have two lambdas. One makes a change in DynamoDb and the second one is triggered when any change in DynamoDb table is made. It works perfectly. My question is how to give input to the second lambda.

I execute first lambda from AWS Console so I can just make a test there with my desired input. But if my second lambda wants to get some parameters from the first lambda which are completely irrelevant for DynamoDb user so I don't want to write them into table what to do? Is there any option to give parameters to the second lambda?

I was thinking about Step function but I'm not sure how it should work.

Comment: Why we need to call the second lambda from the first one? Please clarify again? You can use DynamoDB stream to trigger lambda if there is a change like insert, update ...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use case for a lambda trigger based off a dynamodb stream - you can read about them here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html